# Using Facebook Connect for User Data in Drupal

Tags: drupal, facebook

I have a Drupal site where I want to allow users to add their current Facebook Events that they themselves have created into a custom database.  I'm not looking to use Facebook Connect as a User Management system, just trying to get someone's info after they accept.

More specifically I'm looking for a way to access a user's Facebook events info from a Drupal Page using PHP.  I want them to be able to hit a button and give me access to their events.

Comment: I'll update it to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at http://drupal.org/project/fb and http://www.drupalforfacebook.org/ ?

The FB module works pretty well, is mostly sane to use, and the author is responsive to bug reports.

Comment: I saw that but I wasn't sure if it was for user management or for accessing the api.  Need to investigate further.

Comment: The module is actually comprised of ~8 sub modules that do different things.  User management (FB Connect) is one of the things that it can do, along with API access.  I have one of my peeps using it for a project now, but I can't say for certain whether you can get at events (not part of the scope of this project).

Comment: Yeah I went through the tour on their site and it's pretty intensive.  Looks like the way to go!